# Could someone give an example of this pic?

Tags: circuit-construction, ibm-q-experience, unitarity

[image]

This is a picture from Wiki(*https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_logic_gate*). Can someone give me a simple example by using two qubits?

[image]

Comment: If you apply a unitary $F$ to the first qubit (q[0]), then your state would be the same as if you applied the conjugate transpose $F^\dagger$ to the second qubit (q[1]).  Can you be more specific?

Comment: could you please edit the title to something that reflects what is being asked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Fourier transform and inverse Fourier transform for one qubit is only Hadamard gate, for two qubit case following two circuits are equivalent.

*First circuit (Fourier transform applied on qubit $q_0$)*

[image: Circuit 1]

*First circuit (inverse Fourier transform applied on qubit $q_1$)*

[image: Circuit 2]

Both circuits return state

$$
|\psi\rangle = \frac{1}{2}(|00\rangle + |01\rangle + |10\rangle - |11\rangle).
$$

---

**EDIT:** I have just realized that the gate $F$ is general unitary transformation and not the QFT (I was missleaded by F = Fourier). However, my example is also valid. It is a particular case for two qubits asked for in the question.